# Extract columns from CSV file Python: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)

Tags: python, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGCJA.png)I am trying to extract several columns from a csv file. This is a simple version of a large panel data I am working with. It is somewhat like the following when opened in Excel. However, I got an error message when running my code: "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)". I just edited my file as an image so that it's easier to see.

companyID year company_age Debt_TA gcp
654001  2000    49  0.14    0
654001  2001    50  0.17    0
654001  2002    51  0.23    1
112089  2013    38  0.11    0
112089  2014    39  0.13    0
342980  2007    54  0.15    0
342980  2008    55  0.22    1

I have searched and tried several answers regarding this type of error, but none has worked for me so far. My code is shown below.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from sklearn import feature_extraction

def parseFile (filename):
    companies = list ()
    with open (filename) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader (csvfile, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"')       
        for index, line in enumerate (reader):
            #print index, line
            if (index > 0 and index < 150):
                CompanyID, year, company_age, gcp = line
                #print company_name
                company = {\
                    'CompanyID' : CompanyID,\
                    'year' : year,\
                    'company_age' : company_age,\
                    'gcp': int (gcp),\
                }
                companies.append (company)
    return companies

def extract_year_features (companies):
    year_list = list ()
    for company in companies:
        year_list.append (company['year'] * 10)
    tweet_vectorizer = feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer ()
    X = tweet_vectorizer.fit_transform (year_list).toarray ()
    return X


def extract_company_age_features (companies):
    company_age_list = list ()
    for company in companies:
        company_age_list.append (company['company_age'] * 10)
    tweet_vectorizer = feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer ()
    X = tweet_vectorizer.fit_transform (company_age_list).toarray ()
    return X

def extract_all_features (companies):
    return np.concatenate ( (extract_year_features (companies), \
                          extract_company_age_features (companies)), \
                          axis=1)


def generate_target (companies):
    y = [company['gcp'] for company in companies]
    return np.array (y)

companies = parseFile ("sample.csv")
X = extract_all_features (companies)
y = generate_target (companies)   
#credit to G.Li
```

Can anybody point out anything I had wrong? I am a Python beginner and have tried several answers to similar questions, but none has worked for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Too many values to unpack (expected 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664102/too-many-values-to-unpack-expected-4)

Comment: Suggestion: Use pandas to import and manipulate csv files.

Comment: Thank you to you both, Andrejs Cainikovs and  user9940344. I will look at your suggestions and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

On this line

```
CompanyID, year, company_age, gcp = line
```

It is expecteding to unpack 4 variables, but there are 5 fields in your csv. You need an extra variable for Debt_TA.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response! What I want is not to select all variables, but just a few. The reason is that the big data I am working with is huge, and I don't need all variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the csv reader, in your csv there is not a ',' delimiter, so in this line `CompanyID, year, company_age, gcp = line` fails because all the columns are in the same string, and you have 5 columns in the csv too.

Watch [PEP8 style-guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) too, you have some indentation problems

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you mean this line code when you say no ','            reader = csv.reader (csvfile, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"')    ? I see a ',' there. Can you further explain? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. In your csv de delimeter is a space, no a comma. Maybe this example helps you. https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-csv-files-in-python/

Comment: Thank you for providing the info. I've just checked my code and the csv file, making sure comma is present to both places. After running the code, the same error message occurs. I have worked on this for quite some time, but couldn't figure out.

Comment: If your csv has comma delimeter now, Maybe the answer of @ashish14 helps you. If you debug your app you will see more clear

Comment: Thank you, I will have a try now.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this way since you have 5 fields in the csv file:

```py
CompanyID, year, company_age, gcp = line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3]
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I've just tried your suggestion, and I got a different error message. "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.14'". However, I think this probably is just a type error. There are 5 variables in the csv file, but I only need four of them except the variable named 'Debt_TA'

Comment: I've just tried your advice by changing your "line[3]" to "[line4]" because I don't need column "Debt_TA". It ended with no error message. That's great! However, when I add code "print(X)", it came with something below: print(X)
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]. I don't think this is right since I need to extract the column values. Do you know why? Thanks for the help.